# Virtual Scrolling in Data Table using dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a bar chart and a Data Table with thousands of rows. I want to maintain cross-filtering between charts and also don't want to use any pagination in the table. Both are created with cross filter and dc.js. I want to do virtual scrolling in the Data Table. Is there any way to do virtual scrolling in the Data Table.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far, with a code example? / What do you expect? / What error do you get? For help, take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: By virtual scrolling, do you mean something like infinite scroll, where the content will only be rendered when it appears? dc.js definitely doesn't support this out of the box. It might be supported via datatables and [dc-tableview](https://github.com/karenpommeroy/dc-tableview), not sure.